# Re-Captcha style fix working only through developer tools

Tags: css

I have found this solution to make Re-Captcha responsive, and when inserted directly through **developer tools** on *.g-recaptcha* or *.g-recaptcha iframe*, it works good. However, when I add this style in my text editor, it does not seem to accept it(does the Captcha has own stylesheet that loads after maybe?). What could be the issue, and does anyone know how to solve it or has encountered this..?

Here's my css:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 575px){
    .g-recaptcha iframe {
        transform:scale(0.77);
        -webkit-transform:scale(0.77);
        transform-origin:0 0;
        -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: It seems it had a problem with media query - just remove it, and apply transform(1) from a new media query with (min-width) instead.